# Failed to create bot module in Azure channel

Tags: azure, chatbot, cortana

I added my chatbot to the Cortana channel through Azure, and it worked, however Cortana was telling me that it was unable to open the skill, so I deleted the botlet from the workspace, and then tried to re-add it, however now when trying to add it, I'm getting:

Unable to save.
There was an error saving the channel:

Failed to create bot module. Trace Id : 5daa4c5f-c609-4f57-adfe-65cc7d5bba27

Have you seen this error before? I would appreciate the help.

Thanks!

Comment: i am getting the same exact error.. did you get any resolution for this error?

Comment: It's actually weird, but, it happened to me after I removed the related botleg from the Cortana Workspace and then tried to re-add it from Azure. The solution was to create a "dummy" botleg with the same name of my chatbot in the Workspace, and then try to re-add it from Azure.